# Order by Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I was wondering how to order the following by the `followers()` created at DESC. I think adding orderBy to just that query will sort by the $user?

```
$followers = $user->followers()->limit(12)->get();
```

If it helps any I am using the package https://github.com/rennokki/befriended and am trying to sort by the date the followers were created.

I tried many of these suggestions below. But got it working by adding the following.

```
$followers = $user->followers()->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc')->limit(12)->get();
```

Comment: you can add the orderBy inside followers() reation in user model

Comment: So, you just want the followers for a single user ordered by creation date?

Comment: You use the follow query If you mean just for "one" user's followers to order descandent:
$user->followers()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->limit(12)->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it was a polymorphic relationship I used the following to get it working.

```
$followers = $user->followers()->orderBy('pivot_created_at', 'desc')->limit(12)->get();
```

Answer (score 5):

Eloquent has date filters like `oldest()` and `latest()`

```
$followers = $user->followers()->latest()->limit(12)->get();
```

Answer (score 4):

please try this:

```
$followers = $user->followers()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->limit(12)->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the default order to the relationship. 
Just add `->orderBy('yourColumn')` to your method.

Example:

```
    public function county()  {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\County')->orderBy('name');
    }
```